# My pot no longer percolates water to the top

Tags: brewing-process

My pot has worked fine for six months but has stopped working altogether. No water percolates up into the chamber.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more info. Without that, it's too unclear to provide a good answer.

Comment: Kathy, welcome! “Pot” - could you elaborate, please? There are different kinds that percolate. Do you perhaps mean a Moka? And as @JJJ writes - please give us more details to work with. In general, it’s recommended that new users take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works. You may also want to read [ask] and [edit] your post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use sink water to make coffee?If the answer is yes it could be stuck because of the **lime**.Try the clean with the **anti-lime solution**.Please wash very well after this solution.You can make your own solution with the **vinegar and lime**.